# Plotting vectors in a constrained ordination without labels

Tags: r, plot, vegan

I would like to plot vectors from a capscale ordination using `VEGAN`.
I am familiar with the `display ="bp"` command, but this adds labels that are obscured by site points. Is there an easy means of removing these? I am happy to add them in later i.e. once exported and within word for publication.

My code thus far is as follows:

```
plot(mod, scaling = 3, type="n")
     with(data, points(mod, display="sites", cex=Pointsize,   
     pch=ifelse(Cat=="Reference",21,19)) ,bg=Cat,)
     with(data,text(mod,display="bp"))
```

Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use the `points()` method instead of the `text()` method:

```
points(mod, display = "bp")
```

(There also should be no need for the `with(data)` in that last line of code you show.)

Here is a *reproducible* example:

```
require(vegan)
data(varespec)
data(varechem)
ord <- cca(varespec ~ ., data = varechem)
plot(ord, type = "n", display = "sites")
points(ord, display = "sites")
points(ord, display = "bp")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. I realised that I had an extra and seemingly superfluous `with`, but it seemed to negate an error I was getting. I have removed and fixed with your code. Thanks.

Comment: @Jon If you are happy with the Answer, consider accepting it. See the [as] section of the [faq] on why this is useful for more than my ego :-) Glad you found this helpful.